# Как сделать СВОЮ авторизацию?

Tags: android

В общем, есть сайт с формами, например, логин и пароль, а так же есть кнопка. При нажатии кнопки и при успешной авторизации сайт выбрасывает пользователя на страницу, на которой лежит нужный мне (приложению) текст (объект, не важно). Всё это можно сделать через WebView, в котором открыть страницу авторизации, а потом из этого же WebView'а прочитать текст - тут всё ясно.
А как сделать свою собственную версию такой страницы с двумя EditText'ами и кнопкой, т.е. не показывая пользователю упомянутый выше сайт?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Используйте **GET** или **POST** запросы.

Мой вам совет сделать это через **POST**, если конечно веб-сервис ваш. Это делается в течении минуты, заменой всех **$GET[]** на **$POST[]**. Работа в приложении с выполнением **POST-запроса** выглядит так:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.ru/service.php");

try {
    // определяешь элементы массива POST
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "somedata"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "somedate"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // выполняешь POST-запрос
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Но в случае, если же вы все-таки хотите использовать **GET-запросы** в своем приложении, тогда **"Percent encoding"** вам в помощь, может видели когда-нибудь что-то вроде **http://yoursite.ru/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%**, почитать можно [тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), а потом потратить порядком времени на составления таблицы с кодами символов, или же найти готовое решение. В андроиде выполнение такого запроса будет выглядеть так:

```
//тут нужно определить твои **login** и **pass** с помощью percent encoding
CharSequence login, pass;
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.yoursite.ru/authorization.php?login="+login+"&pass"+pass);
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробные примеры! К этому времени уже сам освоил эти технологии, но примеры всё равно будут очень полезны!